# Update the second spinner based on first spinner item

Tags: android

i have created the two spinner in xml namely myspinner and myspinner1. The myspinner value is obtained from the json value.Based on myspinner item selected,we get the hotel id.That retrieved hotel id is used to call the another AsyncT1.In the AsyncT1 the  myspinner1 value get listed out.My problem is,if i select the myspinner the myspinner1 value is not updated it remains same.I have tried the adapter.notifydatasetchanged() but till now not updated.`

```
class AsyncT extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
            String userID = prefs.getString("userid", null);
            System.out.println("userID---"+userID);

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://airbnb.abservetech.com/demo/public/mobile/hotelroom/hotel");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", userID));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                Log.e("mainToPost", "mainToPost" + nameValuePairs.toString());


         /* execute */

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamToStringExample str = new InputStreamToStringExample();
                responseServer = str.getStringFromInputStream(inputStream);
                Log.d("response", "response -----" + responseServer);

                //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
                // postData(responseServer);

                JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(responseServer);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("Hotel_details");

                //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < jsonArray.length(); i1++) {
                    try {


                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i1);

                        Movie movie = new Movie();

                        movie.setHotelid1(jsonObject.optString("hotel_id").toString());
                        movie.setHotelname1(jsonObject.optString("hotel_name").toString());
                        hotelNames.add(jsonObject.optString("hotel_name").toString());
                        movieList.add(movie);


                        System.out.println("movie list" + movieList);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                Adapter =  (new ArrayAdapter<String>(Edit_room.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, hotelNames));
                                mySpinner.setAdapter(Adapter);
                                Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                                               View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
                                        // Set the text followed by the position
                                        hotelid= (movieList.get(position).getHotelid1());
                                        System.out.println("name--"+hotelid);


                                        new AsyncT1().execute(hotelid);

                                         }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });


                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


        }
    }
```

```
class AsyncT1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

          //  http://airbnb.abservetech.com/demo/public/mobile/hotelroom/roomid?hotel_id=79

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://airbnb.abservetech.com/demo/public/mobile/hotelroom/show");
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
            String userID = prefs.getString("userid", null);
            System.out.println("userID---"+userID);

            /*hotel_id&room_type&room_prize&is_active&available_status&adults_count&room_count&room_images&
                    room_desc&room_name&room_footage&General&Services&Food_Beverages&Outdoors&Activities&
                    Dining&Media_Entertainment&Kitchen&Others*/
            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hotel_id", hotelid));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                Log.e("mainToPost", "mainToPost" + nameValuePairs.toString());


         /* execute */

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamToStringExample str = new InputStreamToStringExample();
                responseServer = str.getStringFromInputStream(inputStream);
                Log.d("response", "viewroomresponse -----" + responseServer);

                JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(responseServer);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("view_room_details");

                //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < jsonArray.length(); i1++) {
                    try {


                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i1);


                        Movie movie = new Movie();


                       // movie.setViewRoomtype(jsonObject.optString("room_type").toString());
                        movie.setViewRoomprice(jsonObject.optString("room_prize").toString());
                        movie.setViewIsActive(jsonObject.optString("is_active").toString());
                        movie.setViewAvailablestatus(jsonObject.optString("available_status").toString());
                        movie.setViewAdultcount(jsonObject.optString("adults_count").toString());
                        movie.setViewRoomcount(jsonObject.optString("room_count").toString());
                        movie.setViewRoomdesc(jsonObject.optString("room_desc").toString());
                        movie.setViewRoomname(jsonObject.optString("room_name").toString());
                        movie.setViewRoomfootage(jsonObject.optString("room_footage").toString());
                        RoomNames.add(jsonObject.optString("room_type").toString());
                        movieList.add(movie);




                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
//                                ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,RoomNames);
//                                Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
//                                Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                                mySpinner1.setAdapter(Adapter);



                                Adapter1 =(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Edit_room.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, RoomNames));
                                if(Adapter1!=null){
                                    Adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    mySpinner1.setAdapter(Adapter1);

                                }
                                else{ mySpinner1.setAdapter(Adapter1);}


                                mySpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                                               View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
                                        // Set the text followed by the position

                                        hotelid= (movieList.get(position).getHotelid1());

                                        room_price.setText(movieList.get(position).getViewRoomprice());
                                        description.setText(movieList.get(position).getViewRoomdesc());
                                        adult_count.setText(movieList.get(position).getViewAdultcount());


                                  }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


        }
    }
```

`

Comment: Write mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener in MainActivity instead.

Comment: thanks for ur answer but its not works

Answer (score 0):

Use this link, it might help you.
http://www.javaknowledge.info/populate-second-spinner-based-on-selection-of-first-spinner/

Comment: i have created dynamic value on second spinner then how i should refresh

Comment: on second spinner click you can call webservice and then fill the adapter and show data

Comment: You are calling second asynctask from fisrt spinner's onItem. But you can try to call second spinner's asynctask on second spinner's click